# Using Factory to Display Navigation for Application?

Tags: angularjs

I am still learning so any advice or improvements would be appreciated! I am looking to build a Navigation for my Angular App using the Service i built if its usable.

Quick Summary of Functionality:

1. User MouseOver Parent Item
2. Submenu Items Display under Active Parent Item

Here is what i have so far for my Service Structure:

```
app.factory("NavigationService", function () {
    var e = [{    
        title: "Parent1",
        type: "parentitem",
        children: [{
            title: "SubofParent",
            type: "subitem",
            href: "/location"
        }]
    }, {
        title: "Parent2",
        type: "parentitem",
        children: [{
            title: "SubofParent",
            type: "subitem",
            href: "/location"
        }]
    }, {
        title: "Parent3",
        type: "parentitem",
        children: [{
            title: "SubofParent",
            type: "subitem",
            href: "/location"
        }]
    }
    }];
});
```

As you can see its a very simple structure but what i would like to know is how i can use this structure to ng-repeat the Parent Items and then display the SubItems on Hover over specific parent item, if that makes sense?

I am unsure how to build the controller to handle this method.
Any Advice on how to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data" >
          <ul ng-mouseover="isChildrenVisible=true" ng-mouseleave= "isChildrenVisible=false"> {{item.title}}</ul> //parent element                
          <ul ng-show="isChildrenVisible">
                <li ng-repeat="child in item.children "> //child element
                    <p>{{child.title}}</p>
                </li>
          </ul>
  </li>
```

Here I make child element hidden by default (initialize isChildrenVisible varible to false). when user mouse over the parent element then I will make **isChildrenVisible=true** and on mouse leave i make this varible false.

Comment: Let me know if you have any other suggestive ways to go about this. This sounds like a vary solid approach in theory. i will test it soon.

Comment: whats needs to be done inside the controller for this to work. I cant get it to display? I presume its something todo with getting the items from the Service to the controller?

Comment: you  need to create scope varible like this $scope.isChildrenVisible=false; $scope.data=NavigationService.e;  in controller.